# How can I use props.children and TypeScript in a functional higher order component that is consumed by class component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am starting to write a HOC but get the error:

> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactElement'

With this code:

```
const ToolsWrapper = (props: ReactElement): ReactElement => props.children;
```

Then with this code:

```js
function ToolsWrapper<T>(Children: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  return (): ReactElement => (
    <>
      {Children}
    </>
  );
}

export default ToolsWrapper;
```

I get the error:

> Type '{ children: (false | Element | undefined)[]; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & ComponentClass<unknown, any>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & FunctionComponent)'.
> Type '{ children: (false | Element | undefined)[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.

Where `ToolsWrapper` is consumed in the parent.

How can I just access props.children?

Comment: `props: ReactElement` doesn't make much sense. Props aren't elements, they're *properties* of elements. What's your expected use of `ToolsWrapper`? What will you be passing it?

Comment: Thanks - to start with I just want the HOC to return its children but once I've got that working I will also pass it a boolean. I've also tried this which does not work: `const ToolsWrapper = ({ children }): ReactNode => children;` - `Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown how you'll use `ToolsWrapper`, but based on the type you've given (`ReactElement`) and the fact you're trying to access `children`, I'm going to guess you're passing it a `ReactElement`, e.g.:

```
ToolsWrapper(<div>...</div>)
```

or

```
ToolsWrapper(<SomeComponent>...</SomeComponent>)
```

If so, you want the `props` property of the element:

```
const ToolsWrapper = (element: ReactElement): ReactNode => element.props.children;
```

(Note that `children` is of type `ReactNode`, see `index.d.ts` in `@types/react` for details.)

Or with destructuring:

```
const ToolsWrapper = ({props: {children}}: ReactElement): ReactNode => children;
```